# AS3 and adobe AIR to make javascript change default browser using the class PrintJob

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, air, flashdevelop

I never worked with AS3, and I want to use it to control the printing process from javascript, but I don't know where to start!

I downloaded FlashDevelop and linked it to the Flex sdk, but I don't know what to do next? how to link things together?

Any help?

Comment: I read this link :http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7cb1.html
and the documentation on PrintJob class. I haven't wrote a line in AS3 in my life, don't know the requirements, I'm just looking for a place to start learning things about it.

Comment: When I downloaded FlashDevelop, added the sdk for AIR 17, and Flex, then run the template app, it gives me the error: "invalid application descriptor: Unknown namespace: http://ns.adobe.com/air/appli
cation/17.0"